# NullPointerException when initializing database adapter class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

In my MainActivity I have another class that needs to insert some record into the database upon an onClick event.
I am getting a Null Pointer Exception, the application crashes and shows the following errors in LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.note.SimpleCalendarViewActivity$GridCellAdapter$2$1.onClick(SimpleCalendarViewActivity.java:442)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
```

This is the MainActivity class:

```
public class SimpleCalendarViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private static final String tag = "SimpleCalendarViewActivity";

    private ImageView calendarToJournalButton;
    private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
    private Button currentMonth;
    private ImageView prevMonth;
    private ImageView nextMonth;
    private GridView calendarView;
    private GridCellAdapter adapter;
    private Calendar _calendar;
    private int month, year;
     NotesDbAdapter adap;
    private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
    private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.simple_calendar_view);

             adap = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        }
```

The following class is inside the SimpleCalendarViewActivity class

```
public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener
        {
                      @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
                {


                    final String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
                    selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bvbnv", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SimpleCalendarViewActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage("New Diary").setTitle("");

                    builder.setNeutralButton("View Diaries", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(SimpleCalendarViewActivity.this);

                             builder2.setMessage("New Diary");

                            LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();

                            builder2.setView(inflator.inflate(R.layout.note_edit, null)).setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    EditText title =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
                                    EditText body = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);


                                    adap.open();

                                    adap.createNote(title.getText().toString(), body.getText().toString(), date_month_year);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    adap.close();

                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                            AlertDialog ad2 = builder2.create();
                            ad2.show();

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            arg0.cancel();

                        }
                    });

                     AlertDialog ad = builder.create();

                    ad.show();





}}
```

I did not share the whole code

Comment: NotesDbAdapter is my database adapter class

Comment: What is line 442 `SimpleCalendarViewActivity.java`.

Comment: _adap.createNote(title.getText().toString(), body.getText().toString(), date_month_year);

Comment: ok check my post now that should fix the problem

Comment: can you post `note_edit.xml` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
final View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.note_edit, null);
builder.setView(v).setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

EditText title =  (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
EditText body = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.body);
```

If your edittext are in  `R.layout.note_edit` then you need to use the inflated view object to initialize your views.

Comment: i need to change builder or builder2 ? and please tell me how to pass the activity context to constructor of the adapter class ?

Comment: @user2870778 that was a typo and there is no need for activity context as you have the adapter as inner class which i failed to notice. You can use ActivityName.this which you already use for alert dialog. Just make the above changes. shoulw work

Comment: @user2870778 `adap.createNote(title.getText().toString(), body.getText().toString(), date_month_year);` if this gives NPE its likely that title or body is null can you post `note_edit.xml` . `adap` is initialized so its not null.

Comment: i resolved the issue , thank you , i was missing the view that you mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Move  `adap = new NotesDbAdapter(this);` from `onCreate` to your `GridCellAdapter` class.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you have not initalized selectedDayMonthYearButton.

```
selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
```

Comment: @user2870778 can you show the full code of adapter class and specify line 442